# How can I build the following layout in Compose?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I am wanting to build the following layout in Compose:

[image]

I have written the following code for this:

```
@Composable
fun MainScreenContent(){
    Surface(
        color = MaterialTheme.colors.primary,
        modifier = Modifier
            .wrapContentWidth(Alignment.CenterHorizontally)
            .wrapContentHeight(Alignment.CenterVertically)
    ) {
        Row() {
            Column(Modifier.weight(0.3F)) {
                Greeting("Android")
                Spacer(Modifier.padding(16.dp))
                Greeting("User")
            }
            Surface(modifier = Modifier.weight(0.4F),
                color = MaterialTheme.colors.primaryVariant,
            ){
                Spacer(Modifier.padding(16.dp))
            }

            Column(Modifier.weight(0.3F)) {
                Greeting("Android")
                Spacer(Modifier.padding(16.dp))
                Greeting("User")
            }
        }
    }

}

@Composable
fun Greeting(name: String) {
    Text(text = "Hello $name!",
        Modifier
            .padding(16.dp), fontSize = 30.sp)
}
```

But with this, I am getting the following output:

[image]

How can I achieve the objective?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set the parent `Surface`'s height to `IntrinsicSize.Max`, and add `fillMaxHeight()` to the inner `Surface`'s modifier.

```
@Composable
fun MainScreenContent() {
    Surface(
        ...,
        modifier = Modifier
            .wrapContentWidth(Alignment.CenterHorizontally)
            .height(IntrinsicSize.Max),
    ) {
        Row {
            ...
            Surface(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .weight(0.4F)
                    .fillMaxHeight(),
                color = MaterialTheme.colors.primaryVariant,
            ) {
                Spacer(Modifier.padding(16.dp))
            }
            ...
        }
    }
}
```